# Calling REST API on splunk alerts and incidents using Postman

Tags: rest, postman, splunk, splunk-query, alerts

I am trying to fetch Splunk alerts, incidents data using GET with Postman. I am getting an HTTP 200 response, but the response is in HTML format with the following error:

> "Splunk relies on JavaScript to function properly. Please enable JavaScript and then refresh the page to login"

Please help with the REST API to fetch Splunk alerts and incidents using Postman?

Comment: what request are you making? please add details of the API you're using so we can help. It seems you are trying to load an URL, and not a REST API endpoint.